# illegal units of measure with textblock

Tags: beamer, textpos

I am 100 % sure this code worked within my presentation I held 2 years ago. I reopened it but I do get the error `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`

```
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{

    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pictures/constraints_column_opak2.pdf}}

\begin{frame}
\LARGE
        \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(100,100)
                        \begin{itemize}
                        \item $\Delta p \propto \frac{1}{d^2}$  
                        \item Pore diffusion
                        \item Column blocking
                        \item Often very expensive

                        \end{itemize}       
        \end{textblock*}

\end{frame}
}
```

If I insert (100pt,100pt) everything works fine. Any ideas what might cause this error ?

Comment: There were updates to `beamer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, if that worked, it was probably by accident.  The `{textblock*}` environment has always required absolute dimensions in its `(100pt,100pt)` argument, not the arguments relative to the `\TPHorizModule` and `\TPVertModule` which `{textblock}` takes.

(Note that textpos v1.8 was recently released, which had a few tweaks in this general area)